# Fullcalender scheduler : cannot get start and end dates using js

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am a beginner in coding. Currently I'm working with Fullcalender's scheduler(free version). I cannot get the start and end dates using javascript. I tried many ways. Someone, please help!!

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',   
      
    slotMinTime :'08:00:00',  //start time to be shown in the grid
    slotMaxTime : '19:00:00', //end time to be shown in the grid    
    height: '100%',
    aspectRatio: 1.8,
    editable: true,
    now: new Date(),
    scrollTime: '00:00', 
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineTenDays,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth,listWeek'
    },
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    views: {
      resourceTimelineTenDays: {
        type: 'resourceTimeline',
        duration: { days: 10 },
        buttonText: '10 days'
      }
    },
    expandRows: true,
    resourceAreaWidth: '10%',
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Machine',
    resources: [
      { id: '1', title: '1' , eventColor: 'blue'},
      { id: '2', title: '7', eventColor: 'green' },
      { id: '3', title: '8', eventColor: 'orange' },
      { id: '4', title: '11', eventColor: 'red'  },
      { id: '5', title: '9', eventColor: 'yellow' },
    ],

    events :'pages/load.php',
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true,
select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
         $('#start').val(start.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")); // here is my issue
         $('#end').val(end.format("Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
         $('#add_Modal').modal('show');   
  });  
  calendar.render();
});
```

---

Is there anything wrong? How shall I get the start and end values. I tried this too.

---

```
var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

---

Comment: Which version of fullCalendar are you using exactly? The syntax is different for each one.

Comment: I am using the latest version: 5.1.0

Comment: Ok. So did you read the v5 documentation for the "select" callback? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback . Notice anything different to the way you've written it? I think you have tried to follow an example from V3. But when it didn't work, did you think to check the documentation?

Comment: Yes. I had already worked with simple Fullcalender V3. And yeah, as you said, tried to follow that. Thanks for your advice. Didn't checked this part of the V5 documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. It was

```
var title = info.event.title; //gives Thu Jul 30 2020 17:30:00 GMT+0900
var start =info.event.start;
```

Thank you all.

Comment: "But need another help"...then please ask another question. Answers are not the place to ask questions...!

Comment: I am sorry. Means, I have to post another question?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You can't ask a question within an answer to a different question!

Comment: OK. II got it. Thank you